# Position text right and left to radio box

Tags: html, css

```html
<div style="left: 300px; position:absolute">
  <label>Radio button Text:<input type="radio"  name="lf-title" value="val"></label>
</div>
```

Code snippet shows current positioning of my radio button and it's related text.
I want to set radio button to the left start position of parent div and move radio button text to right (left align) or left of the radio button (right align) occasionally. (As shown in the image)

[image]

What are the css changes should be done in two occasions?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add a class to the label `left` or `right` to tell the text where it should be aligned and also wrap your text inside a `span`...use `transform` to align the text left or right

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.parent {
  left: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 1px solid red;
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

.parent label {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}

label.left span {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

label.right span {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <label class="left"><span>Text</span><input type="radio"  name="lf-title" value="val"></label>
  <label class="right"><span>Text</span><input type="radio"  name="lf-title" value="val"></label>
  <label class="left"><span>Text</span><input type="radio"  name="lf-title" value="val"></label>
  <label class="right"><span>Text</span><input type="radio"  name="lf-title" value="val"></label>
  <label class="left"><span>Text</span><input type="radio"  name="lf-title" value="val"></label>
  <label class="right"><span>Text</span><input type="radio"  name="lf-title" value="val"></label>
  <label class="left"><span>Text</span><input type="radio"  name="lf-title" value="val"></label>
  <label class="right"><span>Text</span><input type="radio"  name="lf-title" value="val"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion. But I have one more restriction here. I want to draw an outline around the label or parent div. But transform: translate moves the child elements out of parent scope and show child elements outside the outline.

Comment: @hirantha129 see you can do anything you want with css...you will need to make a extra effort for that....and why not that restriction is not there in your question..?...maybe you will need extra markup for that...it will be good if you could share a screenshot of what you want exactly